# How to find difference between two columns in one table across the rows (T-SQL)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query

I have one table called `table1`. This table has three columns `column1` and `column2` and `dates_tart`. Columns `column1`,`column2` has same date type (int) and `date_start` has date type (date). For example, I'm adding a screenshot of this table (MSSQL).

```
Id  column1  column2  date_start
--  -------  -------  ----------
1   1        1        2019-01-20
2   2        2        2019-01-21
3   3        4        2019-02-15
4   4        3        2019-02-17
5   5        6        2019-03-20
6   7        7        2019-03-20
7   8        9        2019-03-20
8   9        8        2019-04-02
9   10       12       2019-04-06
10  14       13       2019-04-07
11  15       0        2019-04-08
12  16       NULL     2019-04-10
```

My desired result:

1/ I need a list of numbers that are in one column but not present in the next column (for example: number 5 is in `column1` but not in `column2` similarly number 12 is in `column2` and not in `column1`). And the resulting values must be in April 2019

2/ I need a list of numbers that are in one column but not present in the next column (for example: number 5 or 10 is in `column1` but not in `column2`) - So result will only contain records from `column1` that are not in `column2`

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE, always include DDL statement (as mentioned in answer) part of the question, consider [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your future question..

Comment: Also please avoid pictures of text. Tabular data may be a little trickier to post but you can format it as code and then it's easy to arrange nicely, see how I did it with your data sample. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `FULL OUTER JOIN` would be one way:

```
create table table1 (column1 int, column2 int null)

insert into table1
values
(1,1),
(2,3),
(3,2),
(10,12),
(5,10)

select *
from table1 t1
full outer join table1 t2
on t1.column1 = t2.column2
where t1.column1 is null or t2.column2 is null
```

Or wrap that in `EXISTS` to get it as a single set.

```
select x.* from table1 x
where exists(
select 1
from table1 t1
full outer join table1 t2
on t1.column1 = t2.column2
where (t1.column1 is null or t2.column2 is null)
and (x.column1 = t1.column1 or x.column2 = t2.column2))
```

Or using two exists

```
select *
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table1 c1 where t1.column1 = c1.column2)
   or not exists (select 1 from table1 c2 where t1.column2 = c2.column1)
```

Or as a single column, of only the numbers.

```
select t1.column1
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table1 c1 where t1.column1 = c1.column2)
union 
select t1.column2
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table1 c2 where t1.column2 = c2.column1
```

Comment: I have one more question:
If I have next "create_date" column in this table that has a data type (date) and I will want to filter the records displayed by some date (between ‘2019-10-01’ and ‘2019-10-31’), how do I put this condition exactly in your statements?
Thank you some much for help

Comment: Just add it to the where clauses.

Comment: 1 / I used your third option (two exists). Here I have tried to add other conditions, but result was still same 


2 / Can you still advise on how to modify your scripts so that each row in column [column1] is compared to all rows in column [column2], but the result will only contain records from “column1” that are not in [column2]?

Comment: I don't understand your issue. You mentioned a date field that wasn't in the sample data. If you update your post with new sample data and expected results, it would be easier to help you out. I can't determine why you aren't getting correct results otherwise, as you see the sample data and scripts i provided work as expected.

Comment: Sorry about that, i updated my post

Comment: In **both** exists clauses, simply add `and date_start >= '20190401' and date_start < '20190501'`

Comment: I tried, but the result doesn't even reflect the date condition


`select * from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table1 c1 where t1.column1 = c1.column2)
   or not exists (select 1 from table1 c2 where t1.column2 = c2.column1) and date_start >= '2019-04-01' and date_start < '2019-05-01'`

And next I have a question how to modify the code to get the result, see point 2 in the topic

Comment: because you need it add it to *both* exists. You added it to the outer query in your comment....

Comment: OK, I'll try it. Could you still help me with point two (in topic)?

Comment: My answer does this @H0nzin. There is nothing more to do.